# Hypersurface separating two halspaces.

Tags: manifolds

I have an hypersurface separating the hyperspace in 2 halfspaces.
How can I found a description (math formulas)for those two halfspaces?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If your surface is defined by $f(x_1, \ldots, x_n) = 0$ for some continuous $f:\Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$, then more likely than not, one half will be $f(x_1, \ldots, x_n) \geq 0$ and the other $f(x_1, \ldots, x_n) \leq 0$. That's the best I can do without knowing more about your hypersurface.